# pandas: working out mean and sum value for each stock in each day

Tags: python, pandas, sum, average

I am working on getting the mean and sum value of volume for every stock in every day.

My data is like

```
 ric    date    volume  
 vod    7-17     43
 vod    7-17     4444
 vod    7-17     53
 vod    7-18     66
 vod    7-19     77
 vod    7-19     29
 ...     ...     ...
 bat    7-17     87
 bat    7-18     99
 ...     ...     ...
```

and I want it convert to

```
ric    date    volume  day_v_vol    day_sum_vol
 vod    7-17     43     1513          4541
 vod    7-17     4444   1513          4541
 vod    7-17     53     1513          4541
 vod    7-18     66      66            66
 vod    7-19     77      53            106
 vod    7-19     29      53            106
 ...     ...     ...     ...           ...
 bat    7-17     87      87            87
 bat    7-18     99      99            99
 ...     ...     ...     ...           ...
```

I used 'groupby' method,

```
grouped=data.groupby(['ric','date'])
data['sumbas']=grouped.sum()
data['avbas']=grouped.mean()
```

**but its not very handy**. After 'groupby', I need to merge the new dataset with the old one.

Anyone can give me some quick method that can directly generate the one I wanted? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of functions to perform on a `groupby` object using `agg`.

```
import numpy as np

grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'ric']).volume.agg([sum, np.mean])
grouped.columns = ['sumbas', 'avbas']

>>> grouped

          sumbas  avbas
date ric               
7-17 bat      87     87
     vod    4530   1510
7-18 bat      99     99
     vod      66     66
7-19 vod     106     53
```

You still need to join it back to your original DataFrame:

```
>>>df.set_index(['date', 'ric']).join(grouped) 

          volume  sumbas  avbas
date ric                       
7-17 bat      87      87     87
     vod      43    4530   1510
     vod    4444    4530   1510
     vod      43    4530   1510
7-18 bat      99      99     99
     vod      66      66     66
7-19 vod      77     106     53
     vod      29     106     53
```

An alternative method is to create a `groupby` object and then iteratively call `transform`:

```
gb_vol = df.groupby(['date', 'ric'])['volume']
for f_name, func in zip(['daily_vol', 'davg_vol'], 
                        [np.sum, np.mean]):
    df[f_name] = gb_vol.transform(func)

>>> df
   ric  date  volume  daily_vol  davg_vol
6  bat  7-17      87         87        87
0  vod  7-17      43       4530      1510
1  vod  7-17    4444       4530      1510
2  vod  7-17      43       4530      1510
7  bat  7-18      99         99        99
3  vod  7-18      66         66        66
4  vod  7-19      77        106        53
5  vod  7-19      29        106        53
```

Comment: hi Alex thanks for your code. I imported both pandas and numpy and applied your code. But system gave me : NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: `df` is just the variable name for whatever dataframe you are using.

Comment: Thanks again.   I changed the variable name. But this time it shows: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'avbas'], dtype='object')

Comment: That is because `avbas` must already be in the original dataframe.  Try using a different name in `grouped.columns = ...`